# Ag-grid restoring the data

Tags: ag-grid

I am using ag-grid to load the data.Once the data has been loaded i would like to save the state of ag-grid and restore  it for future use.Going through the documentation i have understood that i should be using columnApi to save the state.To load the data while restoring the state what are the changes i should make and also where should i call the restore state instead of having a separate button?

```
var gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: columnDefs,
  enableSorting: true,
  enableFilter: true,
  onGridReady: function () {
      gridOptions.columnApi.setColumnState(colState);
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, you have a component called `GridParentComponent` in which you have your `ag-grid` To make it easy to understand, let's just assume that we are just interested in pertaining the `columnState` of the grid as of now.

You have to follow below steps to achieve this.

1. Get the state of the grid before its being unloaded from the DOM. Use 
   **[OnDestroy](https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy)** here.

   - Implement interface `OnDestroy` and in the `ngOnDestroy` function, use `getColumnState()` of [`gridApi`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-api/).
   - Store this data in an angular service, and use it when the user comes again on the same screen.
   - If you also want to persist the grid state even after your browser is closed, you can use `localStorage` or apis such as [ng2-cache](https://npmjs.com/package/ng2-cache) to store the data.
2. Set the state of the grid when its being loaded into the DOM.

   - Inside `onGridReady` event, get the `columnState` data from the cache or preferably from a singleton service which brings back the data from in memory or from `localStorage`
   - Using `gridApi.setColumnState(columnState)`, set the `columnState`.

If you are going to use this functionality at multiple places through your application, I would rather suggest you to use a wrapper component and segregate your logic to perform these actions into this component instead of keeping this logic inside your `GridParentComponent`.